# ASP page links not available when passing through jQuery.html()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I am learning some basic ASP.net development as a hobby. I am using jQuery.html() to update a div with a list of links to ASP razor pages, but the links do not carry through.

I have created a test web app, and attached a jQuery function. The code works, the div populates, but the ASP page links are not active.  I've not been able to find anything specifically about this, but as I am new to the subject, my Google-Fu may be off.

Here is the jQuery code that runs in site.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#testDiv").html(
        '<p>Page List:</p> <ul> <li> <a asp-area="" asp-page="/TestPage">TestPage</a></li></ul>'
    );

});
```

When this runs the div looks like this:

[image: jQuery Div]

When I copy the quoted html code in the js query directly into the page div:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="testDiv">
        <p>Page List:</p> <ul> <li> <a asp-area="" asp-page="/TestPage">TestPage</a></li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The link works correctly as below:

[image: ASP Direct]

Is there something I need to do additionally to the ASP passthrough code to make the links work with jQuery?

Comment: The asp code must be executed on the server - then the Razor C# engine can turn it into HTML to send to the browser. Just hard-coding it into a string in some JavaScript doesn't allow that to happen. If you really need to so this then maybe a partial view loaded via Ajax might be a suitable way to achieve it

Comment: As this is just a hobby project there are no specific requirements on implementation. I will probably just pass html links through instead. Thanks for the answer, you have greatly improved my ASP knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ADyson mentioned in the comments, the `asp-page` attribute is an [Anchor Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.anchortaghelper?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which is rendered into appropriate HTML by the Razor engine. This happens server-side.

What you're doing through jQuery is happening client-side. That is, there is no Razor engine available, so it's rendering as-is. The razor anchor tag helper at the end of the day translates its value into valid HTML.

From jQuery, you have to set the proper HTML for the link:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#testDiv").html(
        '<p>Page List:</p> <ul> <li> <a href="/TestPage">TestPage</a></li></ul>'
    );

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional information and I appreciate the link it really helps. Thats a lot of helpers :D

Comment: Sure is! [Here's another link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that has a bit more on the topic.